# Remove VAT based on company field and country

Tags: commerce, rules

How can I remove tax based on the company field and based on the country. For example:

**In the Netherlands:**

A customer from a company in The Netherlands - He must pay VAT

A customer private in The Netherlands - He must pay VAT

**Outside the Netherlands**

A customer from a company outside the Netherlands - He must pay ***no*** VAT.

A customer private outside the Netherlands - He must pay VAT.

What I have so far is this: If the company field has a value, they don't need to pay VAT. But the problem is now, if they are living in the Netherlands and they place a order from a company they don't have to pay VAT, but people in this country (The Netherlands) need to pay VAT.

[image]

Comment: What module you use? I understend what you want to do but we need more informacions..:) Are you use Drupal 7 or 8..?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Drupal 7: Drupal Commerce and Rules. Let me know when you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I got the right settings now, but I have one problem. I want to show my product prices always with VAT. But with my current settings in rules the price is showing without VAT until I make a country selection on the checkoutpage.

[image]

In the view I selected: Display the calculated sell price for the current user.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!